# Assembler. Algorithm for incrementing a decimal number

Tags: algorithm, converting, assembly, x86, nasm

I share an algorithm that I have written myself. It is useful for incrementing any digit of a decimal number. That way, a conversion to decimal is not necessary.

Please excuse the mistakes. I am learning assembler and x86 architecture. I am sure that it is possible to improve and optimize it (thank you). This code obviously uses recursion. But it doesn't go through the unnecessary digits. Following the advice of [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61481672/11688616). I think the algorithm is very readable thanks to the labels. It is written using the NASM syntax. Tested on Intel i3 x86-64 CPU and Linux operating system.

```
section .data
  number db "////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////";For 64-digits integers
  countN dd 0
section .bss
  index resb 1 
section .text
  global CMAIN
INCREMENT:
  ;xor rax, rax
  ;mov eax, [index]
  cmp byte[number+eax], "9" 
  jz EQUAL
  jmp checkNEWdigit
EQUAL:
  mov byte[number +eax],"0"
  dec eax
  jmp INCREMENT
NEWdigit:
  mov byte[number + eax],"1"
  inc byte[countN]
  jmp FINISH
checkNEWdigit:
  cmp byte[number + eax],"/" ;check if the position is empty
  jz NEWdigit
  inc byte[number+eax]
FINISH:    
  ret
    
CMAIN:

;Set the number to be increased- For example:    
mov byte[number+59],"9"; Ten thousands
mov byte[number+60],"9"; Thousands
mov byte[number+61],"9"; Hundreds
mov byte[number+62],"9"; Tens
mov byte[number+63],"9"; Ones
;Until 64 digits
mov byte[countN],5 ;Set the number of digits that the number has at the beginning.

mov [index],byte 63 ;Set the position to be increased(63-ones;62-Tens;61-Hundreds..etc..),
xor rax, rax
mov eax, [index];the use of the variable "index" is for readability only.
call INCREMENT

;the next instructions are needed to calculate the position to be printed
mov rbx, 64 ;total of digits
sub rbx, [countN] ;sub number of digits used   
add rbx,number;add the base   
;print
xor rax,rax
mov rax, 1 
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, rbx
mov rdx, [countN]
syscall
;exit
mov rax,60
mov rdi, 2

syscall
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This code obviously uses recursion.

That's not the case. For recursion your *INCREMENT* routine would have to `call` itself which it doesn't. The *INCREMENT* subroutine simply iterates over the characters in the text.

You're right that there is room for improvement. I'll share these observations with you.

> ```
> xor rax,rax
> mov rax, 1
> ```

It's not useful to clear `RAX` right before loading it with a value that is going to overwrite the whole qword anyway.
Writing to the low dword of a 64-bit register will automatically zero out the high dword.

The above code simply becomes `mov eax, 1`. You can apply this several times using different registers.

> ```
> mov byte[countN],5
> sub rbx, [countN]
> mov rdx, [countN]
> mov eax, [index]
> ```

You have defined *countN* as a **dword** variable but the program is using it both as a **byte** and as a **qword**!
You have reserved a single **byte** for the *index* variable but your program is also using it as a **dword**!
Always use your variables for what size they really have. Don't count on the fact that your *index* variable happens to be the last item in the .BSS and that your program worked well because of this.

---

> ```
> mov byte[number+59],"9"; Ten thousands
> mov byte[number+60],"9"; Thousands
> mov byte[number+61],"9"; Hundreds
> mov byte[number+62],"9"; Tens
> mov byte[number+63],"9"; Ones
> ```

You can initialize the integer number "99999" using fewer instructions:

```
mov  rax, "///99999"      (*)
mov  [number+56], rax
```

(*) The x86-64 architecture only allows 64-bit immediates on register loads. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771323/why-we-cant-move-a-64-bit-immediate-value-to-memory/62772299?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C36.9102#62772299) for more info.

---

> ```
> mov rbx, 64 ;total of digits
> sub rbx, [countN] ;sub number of digits used   
> add rbx,number;add the base
> ```

Calculating the address where the number starts only needs these 2 instructions, and because you need this in `RSI`, why not calculate it in `RSI`:

```
lea  esi, [number+64]
sub  esi, [countN]
```

---

> ```
>   jz EQUAL
>   jmp checkNEWdigit
> EQUAL:
> ```

Code like this should use the opposite condition and shave off the extra jump:

```
  jnz checkNEWdigit
EQUAL:
```

---

> I think the algorithm is very readable thanks to the labels.

You're right that it is readable, but then again it is also some kind of spaghetti code with all that jumping around!

If you can accept using another character like "**:**" for the non-occupied positions, then your *INCREMENT* subroutine would only need 1 comparison instead of the current 2.
The trick is to choose a character that is above the character "9" in the ASCII set.
Below is my rewrite that reduces the number of instructions that are needed:

```
INCREMENT:
  cmp  byte [number+rax], "9"   ; "0123456789:"
  jb   .Increment
  mov  byte [number+rax], "0"
  ja   .NewDigit
  dec  eax
  jmp  INCREMENT
.NewDigit:
  inc  dword [countN]
.Increment:
  inc  byte [number+rax]
  ret
```

Please notice that creating a new digit happens in 2 steps: first "0" is written over the ":" and then that zero is incremented. Because creating a new digit happens rarely, this can't possibly make the code any worse. It does however produce clean code.

You've done well to not include code that checks for an overflow after the 64th digit. Who would still be around to see that happen?

Comment: Thank you. I will apply the changes. I thought I could name recursion. I only use the basic instructions because I have a lot to learn.Thank you very much also for this ":"

Comment: I have needed to use this to get it to work,  `mov rax, ":::19999"   mov qword   [number+56],rax`  To what is due?  Is it better to use this to maintain 32bit compatibility?   `mov eax, ":::9"   mov dword [number+56],eax   mov eax, "9999"   mov dword [number+60],eax`  –

Comment: By the way, now I'm using 32-bit registers, and initialized _countN_ with **dd**. and reserving _index_ with **resd**. It is right?

Comment: Thanks, a much better code has been left. I have verified that everything works.  Instead of modifying it in the question. I have marked your answer as valid so that the improvements can be appreciated. I didn't know how to nest labels.  The basis of the OOP resides in this anination mechanism?

Comment: @FER31 Sorry you had to change `mov qword [number+56], "///99999"` . It was my mistake. It had slipped my mind that x86-64 can only use 64-bit immediates on register loads and not eg. on moves to memory. And about using 4 `EAX` instructions vs 2 `RAX` instructions, I would choose `RAX` in this case. Also using `resd` is correct.

Comment: @Sep: *Writing to the low dword of a 64-bit register will automatically zero out the high dword if the value is at most 2GB-1.* - You seem to be mixing up two things.  Writing the low 32 bits, like `mov eax, -1`, will *always* zero-extend and clear the high bits of RAX, allowing 64-bit values of 0..4G-1. [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137).  Writing the whole 64-bit register with a value between 0 and 2^31-1 will zero the high half. So NASM can optimize `mov rax, 1` into `mov eax, 1` for you.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for noticing my mistake. It shows I'm not an x86-64 guru, although the 1st revision had it right in this respect :-).

Comment: Also, `[number+eax]` should be `[number+rax]`.  When you know EAX is already zero-extended into RAX, there's no advantage to override the addressing to 32-bit instead of the default 64-bit.  (@FER31).  Although I probably would have used a pointer, instead of hard-coding the address of static storage into the increment function, not least because then it's usable in a PIE executable or on MacOS, not dependent on `number`'s absolute address fitting into a sign-extended disp32.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are you referring to a pointer to `[number]`?

Comment: @FER31: Yeah, you could have the caller use `lea`, and pass a pointer to the least-significant digit.  And pass `countN` in a register, to be returned in EAX.  So the same program could use this function for two different counters easily if it wanted to.